# Mock IAuthSession.GetOAuthTokens

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, servicestack, moq

I have a Service Stack Service that uses the following code

```
public MyResponse Get(MyRequest request){
    var authSession = GetSession();
    var tokens = authSession.GetOAuthTokens("somekey");

    var jwt = JwtPayload.Deserialize(tokens.AccessTokenSecret);
    var clientId = jwt.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "client_id").Value;

//...
```

I am creating a unit test around this service function, but it seems that GetOAuthTokens is a static extension method which cannot be Mocked by Moq (or by any Mocking framework for that example).

This is my current test function

```
    [Test]
    public void Get_ShouldReturnListOfApplications()
    {

        using (new BasicAppHost(typeof(ApplicationService).Assembly).Init())
        {
            var req = new MockHttpRequest();
            req.Items[SessionFeature.RequestItemsSessionKey] =
                new AuthUserSession
                {
                    UserName = "Mocked",
                    RequestTokenSecret="test",
                    ProviderOAuthAccess = new System.Collections.Generic.List<IAuthTokens>() { MockTokens.Object }
                };

            using (var service = HostContext.ResolveService<ApplicationService>(req))
            {
                service.Client = MockServiceClient.Object;
                service.Settings = MockSettingsProvider.Object;

                var response = service.Get(TestApplicationRequest);

            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to mock the results of that "GetOAuthTokens" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the implementation of the [GetOAuthTokens() extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/61279107cc9c3882126f4ac19708b96f995c990f/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs#L116):

```
public static IAuthTokens GetOAuthTokens(this IAuthSession session, string provider)
{
    foreach (var tokens in session.ProviderOAuthAccess)
    {
        if (string.Compare(tokens.Provider, provider, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            return tokens;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So it should be returning all tokens in `session.ProviderOAuthAccess` where the `provider == "somekey"`